# Can I manage my Bluemix account using an API instead of CF tool?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Can I manage my Bluemix account using an API instead of CF tool? I don't like the output from using the tool and I don't always have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the environment variable CF_TRACE=true to see the API calls made by the cf cli.    Also, see the API docs here https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/